# Incluir codigo R en una aplicacion Shiny

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rstudio, shiny

Amigos, quisiera saber si se puede incluir Script de R en una aplicación Shiny App. He trabajado en varios Script de R que realizan diferentes cosas como obtener nubes de palabras, histogramas, etc. Todo esto a partir de archivos CSV importados. Ademas, utilizo mucho librerías como **Sqldf** para limpiar y trabajar mejor los **data.frame.**.
Pero ahora, quise realizar una interfaz grafica para todos estos pequeños Script y me veo con la sorpresa que no los puedo incluir.

Quisiera incluir, por ejemplo este código que saca una muestra aleatoria de un archivo e incluirlo en una App de Shiny:
**Codigo del Script de R**

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

carpeta<-"/Users/obervatorio/Desktop"
carpeta_Bases<-paste(carpeta,"Bases",sep="/")
nombres<-dir(carpeta_Bases)
nombres<-as.data.frame(nombres)

if(dir.exists(paste(carpeta, "Resultados", sep = "/")))
{}else{
 dir.create(paste(carpeta, "Resultados", sep = "/"))    
}
for(i in 1:length(nombres[,1]))
    archivo_temporal<-paste(carpeta_Bases,toString(nombres$nombres[i]),sep="/")
    consulta <- read.csv(archivo_temporal,header = TRUE,sep = ",",encoding = "UTF-8")
    respuesta <- sqldf('select "screen_name","user_id","status_id","text", "retweet_text","is_retweet"  from    consulta ')

x <-sample(1:length(consulta[,1]),1000,replace = FALSE)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
if(length(respuesta[,1])>=1000)
{
  respuesta<-respuesta[x[,1],]
  archivo_final<-paste(carpeta,"Resultados",sep = "/")
  write.csv(respuesta,file = paste(archivo_final,nombres$nombres[i],sep = "/"),row.names = FALSE)

}else{
  respuesta <- respuesta[1:length(consulta[,1]),]
  archivo_final<-paste(carpeta,"Resultados",sep = "/")
  write.csv(respuesta,file = paste(archivo_final,nombres$nombres[i],sep = "/"),row.names = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Henry Morgan a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Si claro que se puede, de hecho un app shiny es básicamante código R. Por favor, trata de hacer más concreta a tu pregunta, que significa que no los puedes incluir? incluir en dónde? cómo? agrega el código de tu app shiny y del script que no puedes incluir. Saludos.